# C API and getting raw socket

Tags: mysql, c, multiplexing

I'm writing app that needs to commuicate with mysql. Its a single threaded application that uses epoll linux system call for multiplexing clients, but the problem is that everything stalls whenever I'm doing (heavy) queries to database. So I thought to get actual socket from mysql and put it into my epoll so I could multiplex database too. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Article http://jan.kneschke.de/2008/9/9/async-mysql-queries-with-c-api/ answers the question. Works with MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Dead link. Google's cached: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cfftwhpBAS0J:jan.kneschke.de/2008/9/9/async-mysql-queries-with-c-api/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Also a dead link. Wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20140220042427/http://jan.kneschke.de/2008/9/9/async-mysql-queries-with-c-api/

Comment: It lives again here: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/async-mysql-queries-with-c-api/

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more complicated than that. If "everything stalls" (can only guess at what you technically mean by that) then your MySQL server is probably overloaded. Multiplexing a single connection is not only probably not going to work, but it's not going to get around that root issue, either.

Instead, fix your queries and indexes so that no huge table scans and filesorting occurs.

Comment: there are 7 requests to db, only 2 of them are slow ones, others are using different tables and are really simple (executed immediately). Its impossible to optimize them even more, they're checking almost 300k records (data transfer logs), so my issue is with just this multiplexation. Nothing else.

Comment: @Daniel: 300k records isn't very much at all. If this makes "everything stall" then something is very wrong with your queries and indexes. _That_ is your problem. Nothing else.

Comment: (As I already stated, arbitrarily multiplexing a connection to your database won't make the database perform any faster. All you're going to do is break stuff.)